# ERROR when trying to build chromium on my own computer

Tags: python-2.7, build, chromium, ninja

Right now, I am tring to build Chromium on my own computer under instructions at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Build-Chromium

At first, it went smoothly. However when I run

```
$ autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

when I run this to start build. It started. And then an error occured and the build process is terminated.

The error is
`NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined"` and I know it is a common error associated with the difference between python2 and python3.

However, I don't know how to let the ninja use only python2 and avoid this bug.

If you can help me, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: You should have mentioned the operating system too

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My OS is Manjaro 20.2.1 Nibia
and kernel is x86_64 Linux 5.10.19-1-MANJARO

Comment: Follow the instructions here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md

Comment: Thanks you. But I have seen it and it cannot help with my problem. Anyway, still thanks for your advice. I guess I will spend a lot of spare to fix this strange python2or3 problem.

Comment: You should look at the section: `Install depot_tools` where the OS will give precedence to the Python version based on which ever comes first in the `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue when attempting to home build the Brave browser, which is chromium based. It appears that chromium build is based on python2, which is fine, but uses plain calls to "python" in the scripts. Obviously, essentially all modern distros put a symlink to python3 at python in the PATH (generally /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3). I still retain hope that there is a way to configure the "python path" in the build system, but have not found it and I am not too familiar with ninja.

The first way I "solved" this, and managed a successful build is one I consider a hack and do not recommend as a solution without the stipulation that it leaves your system broken so don't run too many other things. This is to manually temporarily update the symlink. Assuming you have both /usr/bin/python2 and /usr/bin/python3 on your system, remove the symlink at /usr/bin/python and replace it with one to python2:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

You can then run the chromium build, and reverse the above change when completed. Note that anything on your system that requires python3 to be at the symlink python cannot be run during this time. I have successfully used this technique to build Brave (and then reverse the change after the build completed).

I can offer you some other options too. One is to set up pyenv. If you search for that, you will find it is a suite that allows you to manage multiple python versions and have different directories use different ones. I researched this, and assume it can work, but have not done it myself.

The next option, which I am currently undertaking right now, is basically a manual watered down version of what pyenv does. I will let you know how it goes. The essence is to add a symlink in the path that will redirect python calls for that instance of the shell (and all subshells it creates). Assuming you are in the source directly at the obvious path:

```
mkdir .shims
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 .shims/python
export PATH=/home/yourname/src/Chromium/.shims:$PATH
python --version
```

This should print out whatever version of python2 you have rather than python. Anytime you come back to work here, you have to export the new PATH again. The rest of your system is unaffected, and still finds python3 at python. You can open up a new terminal and type `python --version` to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

I have Chromium building on Fedora 33.  Somewhere in the Chromium build, /usr/bin/python is getting run explicitly. On Fedora, that means Python 3.

If you change /usr/bin/python to point to python2.7, I bet your build will work.

Creating aliases for "python" won't work.

If this works, consider using the alternatives command to easily change /usr/bin/python:

[alternatives command for /usr/bin/python](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux)